# Is it possible for jaxb to show more error during validation based on xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an xml file and I want to validate it with an xsd. I'm using the Validator.java from jaxb 2.2.5 -old prj- to solve this task. During the validation, if the validator encounter an error, it kills the further validation process. I'm looking for a solution, the Validator class not to stop the validation if encounter a validation error but continue the process to show more errors in case. 
I want to decide from code, if the validation error is a "really" error >> I have problem with the xsd but I can't change it...
Ideas?

Comment: Since the primary purpose of JAXB is to use the schema for constructing Java objects with validation being just a side-effect, you may be better off validating outside the context of JAXB.

Comment: `xmllint`:  It is useful for detecting errors both in XML code and in the XML parser itself.  -from the manual

Answer (score 0):

- I assume you are using `unmarshal` method call of `jaxb library` to get object from the `xml`.
- In that case, If the you have not provided valid `schema document` or valid `xml document` corresponding to that schema, `jaxb library` will throw `UnmarshalException` exception.You cannot proceed further if exception occurs while parsing xml.
- you can [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal)